# how to create distinct list from 2 fields with XSLT

Tags: xslt, distinct-values

I have a list with values which could be repeated, in example:

```
<dates>
    <date>
        <month>January</month>
        <year>2015</year>
    </date>

    <date>
        <month>January</month>
        <year>2016</year>
    </date>

    <date>
        <month>February</month>
        <year>2015</year>
    </date>

    <date>
        <month>January</month>
        <year>2016</year>
    </date>
</dates>
```

Would like to receive list with distinct list:
January 2015
February 2015
January 2016

Not sure is possible and may I edit code below with foreach:

```
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(.)"/>
    </li>
```

or with:

```
    <li>
        <xsl:foreach select="//dates/date[not(.preceding::*)]"?
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordering the entities can be achieved with the following XSLT 1.0 template. It eliminates duplicates and sorts by `year`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="someDate" match="date" use="concat(month/text(),' ',year/text())" />

  <xsl:template match="/dates"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="date[generate-id() = generate-id(key('someDate',concat(month/text(),' ',year/text()))[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="year/text()" />      
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(month/text(),' ',year/text())" /><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result is**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
January 2015
February 2015
January 2016
```

However, it doesn't sort the month's names, it just sorts the years.

If you like to surround the results with `li` elements, replace the `xsl:value-of` with

```
<li>   
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(month/text(),' ',year/text())" /> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shall do:

`distinct-values(/dates/date/concat(month, ' ', year))`

The xpath is to select the concatenation of `month` and `year`, and then select the `distinct-values` among them.